# Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{2-x}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Can someone show how to find the Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{2-x}$?

I tried this: $\frac{1}{2-x}=\frac{1}{1-(x-1)}$ and then use that $ \ T_n(\frac{1}{1-x})=1+x+\dots +x^n.$ But this gives $1+(x-1)+\dots +(x-1)^n$ which is the wrong answer. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you find it about the point $x=0$.
$$ \frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{2(1-x/2)} = \frac{1}{2}( 1+x/2+x^2/2^2+\dots\,. ). $$

**Added:** If you want to derive the Taylor series at $x=1$ then you can advance like this

$$  \frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{1-(x-1)}. $$

Now let $t=x-1$ which gives

$$ T_n(\frac{1}{1-t}) = 1+t+\dots+t^n. $$

Substitute back $t=x-1$ gives what you have

> $$T_n(\frac{1}{1-t}) = = 1+(x-1)+\dots+(x-1)^n. $$

Comment: Thanks! what is wrong with the method that i have tried?

Comment: @rockstar123: What's $T_n\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$?

Comment: Please check the edit i have made to the question!

Comment: @rockstar123: What point have you been asked to find Taylor series at? Is it $x=1$ or $x=0$?.

Comment: it hasn't been mentioned as such in the question. this is a question from Tom Apostol's Calculus I.

Comment: @rockstar123: What you have is the truncated Taylor series at the ponit $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Full detail was not given, but I expect that from $\frac{1}{1-(x-1)}$ you intended to produce the degree $n$ polynomial
$$1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\cdots +(x-1)^n.$$
This is indeed **a** Taylor polynomial for our function. In general, there is no such thing as **the** Taylor polynomial. We must specify how many terms the polynomial should have, and what $a$ we are expanding about.

The polynomials of shape $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+\cdots$ are a special case of a Taylor polynomial for our function, often called a *Maclaurin polynomial*.

That said, expansion about $a=0$ is by quite a bit the most common, and it may be the *intended* interpretation of "Taylor polynomial" in this problem. One could even call it the *default* interpretation. However, it definitely is not the *only* possible interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try this:

$$\frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-(n+1)}x^n$$

Your method gives the Taylor expansion around $x=1$ with radius of convergence of $|x-1| < 1$ so for $x = 0$ you have $|x-1| = |-1| = 1 \not < 1$ you are on the boundary of the radius of convergence and you could end up with a delicate case.

$$\frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{1-(x-1)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x-1)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}x^k \\ \stackrel{*}{=} \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \binom{n}{0}(-1)^n + \sum_{n=1}^m \binom{n}{1}(-1)^{n-1}x + \ldots + \sum_{n=k}^m \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}x^k + \ldots$$

$(*)$ is alowed when we have convergence (wich we don't  at $x=0$ as we will see). Note that at $x=0$  the first sum is divergent and the other ones are $0$. So you can see that we don't have convergence for $x=0$ in the Taylor expansion around $x=1$.

Note that the Taylor expansion at $x=0$ is often called Maclaurin series. If that's what you wanted then the method at the top is the one to go, otherwise, your method is a correct Taylor expansion, but centered at $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks! what is wrong with the method that i have tried?

Answer (score 0):

We want to find $a_0, a_1, a_2,\ldots$ so that  $$\frac1{2-x} = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots.$$

Multiply both sides by $2-x$: $$
\begin{align}
1 & = (2-x)a_0 + (2-x)a_1x + (2-x)a_2x^2 + \cdots\\
& = (2a_0-a_0x)+(2a_1x-a_1x^2) + (2a_2x^2 - a_2x^3) + \cdots \\
\end{align}$$

Combine like terms:

$$ 1 = 2a_0 + (2a_1-a_0)x + (2a_2 -a_1)x^2 + \cdots$$

Equate coefficients on both sides:

$$\begin{align}
2a_0 & = 1 \\
2a_1 - a_0 & = 0 \\
2a_2 - a_1 & = 0 \\
& \vdots
\end{align}$$

Now just solve the equations starting with the top one:

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \frac12 \\
a_1 &= \frac14\\
a_2 &= \frac18 \\
& \vdots
\end{align}$$